# Nodejs Mongoose Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to switch to mongoose from using just the native mongodb and having some trouble.

Connecting to the db as I did previously works fine:

```
var db;

var passDb = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!db) {
        mongo.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI, function(err, database) {
            if (err) throw err;
            db = database;

            req.db = db;
          next();
        });
    } else {
      req.db = db;
      next();
    }
}
```

But the way I'm trying to do it now throws an error:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');

var Poll         = require('./app/models/poll');

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!
});
```

The error:

```
connection error: { [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017
]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017' }
```

Any ideas what is causing this?

edit: it works when I use the database uri directly, but not when I use the environment variable. I have checked and triple checked that everything is typed correctly, it refuses to use the environment variable and I have to put it directly in the code :S

Comment: Did try logging `process.env.MONGOLAB_URI` to the console to ensure it is set (to a valid URI)?

Comment: I would suspect that the `MONGOLAB_URI` environment variable is not set.

Comment: mongolab uri is set and is valid, like i said using native mongo works fine.

Comment: Maybe related to `MONGOLAB_URI` format. Can you show what exactly `MONGOLAB_URI` looks like?

Answer (score 8):

adding `directConnection=true` to connection string worked for me

```
mongoose.connect("MONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/test-db?directConnection=true
");
```

Comment: Been stuck at this problem for an hour, this is the only solution that worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I figured out my mistake, I was connecting to the database before calling `require('dotenv').load();`. Mystery solved!

`mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI);` now works!

Comment: I was facing this same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

i think you forget to define the env variable 
or maybe you forget to call config method of dotenv packages on server or starter file
config it

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config()
```

on your watched file or starter...
then use process.env.VARIABLE
or for testing you mongo connection use simple string url
like that :

> mongodb://localhost:27017/database_name